# The maps $\delta: V \to B \otimes V$ and $\delta': V \otimes V^* \to B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $B$ be a coalgebra and $V$ a vector space. Suppose that we have a coaction $\delta: V \to B \otimes V$. Is the map $\delta$ equivalent to a map $\delta': V \otimes V^* \to B$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have finiteness conditions on $V$? The $\delta$ will always give a $\delta'$, but not the reverse I think. Also I don't think it will be easy to state coassociativity from this point of view... Where does this question come from? (Also, in general there are coactions of *co*algebras on comodules, not of algebras... No?)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, thank you very much. Yes, $B$ should be a coalgebra. I will edit the post.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, yes, I think that if we have $\delta$, then $\delta'$ can be defined as $\delta'(f, g^*) = <f_{(1)}, g^*> f_{(0)}$,  where $\delta(f) = \sum f_{(0)} \otimes f_{(1)}$.